# Select choice in symfony2

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, symfony-forms

I spent hours to find a solution to my problem, and I hope to find the answer here.

Here is the code for my form(ExperienceType) :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('intitulePoste')
            ->add('entreprise')
            ->add('dateDebut')
            ->add('dateFin')
            ->add('mission')
            ->add('idContrat', 'entity', array(
                            'class' => 'ClasseBundle:Contrat',
                            'property' => 'contrat',
                           // 'property_path' => false,
                             'multiple' => false,
                             'mapped' => true,
                            'empty_value' => 'Contrat',
                            // 'expanded'=> true,
                             ))
            ->add('idville', 'entity', array(
                            'class' => 'ClasseBundle:Ville',
                            'property' => 'nom',
                           // 'property_path' => false,
                             'multiple' => false,
                             'mapped' => true,
                             'attr' => array(
                                            'class' => 'lesvilles'
                                ), 
                             'empty_value' => 'Ville',

                             ))
        ;
    }
```

And here is the method that is responsible for registering the entity in the database :

```
public function testAction()
    {
        $exp = new Experience();
        $form = $this->createForm(new ExperienceType(), $exp);
        $request = $this->get('request');
        if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') 
        {
            $form->bind($request);
            if ($form->isValid()) 
            {
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $exp = $form->getData();
                $exp->setIdMembre($this->idMembreAction());
                $em->persist($exp);
                $em->flush();
                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('test'));
            }
        }

                return $this->render('MembreBundle:Default:FormExp.html.twig', array(
                    'form' => $form->createView()));
    }
```

When I validate my form I get this error: "**HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error)**"
then using the file **dev.log** I read this message:

> doctrine.DEBUG: INSERT INTO Experience (idContrat, idMembre, idVille,
>   intitulePoste company, StartDate, EndDate, mission) VALUES {"1"
>   (,,,,,,,????): "[object ] (project \ \ ClasseBundle \ \ Entity \ \
>   Contract: {}) "," 2 ": 1," 3 ":" [object] (project \ \ ClasseBundle \
>   \ Entity \ \ City: {}) "," 4 "," ggg "," 5 ":" waffle "," 6 ","
>   2222/22/22 "," 7 "," 2222/22/22 "," 8 ":" hjjhjhj "} []

So I added in the ExperienceType file a condition on both idVille and idContart fields (***required false***) 
and I added in the Experience.php file (entity) that both fields accept the null  values ​​(***nullable = true***)
when I validate my form my entity is stored in the database with no problem.
So what's the problem? thanks

Comment: You don't need the line `$exp = $form->getData();`. The `$exp` is already mapped with the form and so contains all the data. Try to leave that statement out. Try call the request in the `dev` evnoirement to see a more detailed error message.

Comment: thank you very much 
the probleme was `class could not be converted to string in C:\wamp\www\Symfony\vendor\doctrine-dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Statement.php` and the solution is must to add method __toString. thank you :D

Comment: your welcome. want me to add this as an answer?

Comment: @byf-ferdy yes you can

Answer (score 1):

You probably mapped the objects in wrong way. 
I see in you form field named `idContrat`, which suggest you try to store id property of object `Contract`. That's why you needed `__toString()` method in that object.

You mapping should look more like that:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne("You\SomeBundle\Entity\Contract")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="contract_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * /
protected $contract;
```

than:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="idContract", type="integer")
 * /
protected $contract_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

[byf-ferdy's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17122475/select-choice-in-symfony2#comment24778623_17122475) of removing the `$exp = $form->getData();` looks correct.

For others with similar issues, http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/book/forms.html#forms-and-doctrine has more information on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the line `$exp = $form->getData();` because it returns the data as an `array` and not as an object. Because you passed the `$exp` variable to the `createForm()` method your entity is automatically mapped to your form.

Comment: This is not the case. Form always return what you binded - if you binded array it will return array, if object then object is returned. @2dar didn't written where he added to string method, but probably on object `Contract`